# Classic ASP - Simple Script Timing Out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'm trying to write a very very simple script for a search function in a site using Classic ASP. As follows:

```
<%

Dim keyword, page   
set Cnt=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
keyword = Request.QueryString("s")
page = Cint(Request.QueryString("p"))

Function openDB()
        DSN="Driver={SQL Server};Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=db_xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx"
    Cnt.Open(DSN)
End Function

Function closeDB()
    Cnt.Close()
End Function

If (page = 0) Then
    page = 1
End If

If (Trim(keyword) <> "") Then   

        openDB()

        strSQL = "WITH OrderedResults AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by memorialid) as RowNumber FROM memorials WHERE bg LIKE '%2%') SELECT * FROM OrderedResults WHERE RowNumber between 1 and 5"

        set rs = cnt.execute(strSQL)                

        While NOT rs.EOF

            Response.Write(rs("name"))

        Wend    

        closeDB()
End If


%>
```

The problem is, this script just keeps timing out. There are only 5 records in the table at the moment, and when I run the SQL directly in Managment Studio it brings back results in miliseconds. Can anyone help me figure out why this script takes so long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the important `rs.movenext`

```
    While NOT rs.EOF

        Response.Write(rs("name"))
        rs.movenext

    Wend
```

otherwise your code never exits the loop as it keeps printing the same record..